# Yii: при использовании IN в запросе, приходит неверный результат

Tags: php, yii

Пишу метод для получения логов:

```
public static function getLastCrash($plc_id, $limit = 1, $desc = FALSE)
    {
        if (is_array($plc_id))
        {
            $plc_id = implode(',', $plc_id);
        }

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->condition = 'plc_id IN (:plc_id)';
        $criteria->params = array(':plc_id' => $plc_id);

        if ($desc == TRUE)
        {
            $criteria->order = 'id DESC';
        }
        else
        {
            $criteria->order = 'id';
        }
        $criteria->limit = $limit;

        $a = self::model()->findAll($criteria);
        return $a;
    }
```

тест:

```
$lastCrashes = CrashLog::getLastCrash(array(354,176,355), 20, TRUE);
```

Для всех трёх id есть записи, но по какой-то причине возвращаются записи только для id 354

**P.s.**
Аналогичный запрос работает нормально:

```
select * from test.crashlog WHERE plc_id IN (354,176,355) order by id DESC;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам дурак :)
Надо было юзать [addInCondition](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria/#addInCondition-detail)

Comment: вместо:

        if (is_array($plc_id))
        {
            $plc_id = implode(',', $plc_id);
        }
        ...
        $criteria->params = array(':plc_id' => $plc_id);

написать это:

        $criteria->addInCondition('plc_id', (array) $plc_id)


Но на мой взгляд правильнее было бы сразу передавать массив:

        public static function getLastCrash(array $plc_id, $limit = 1, $desc = FALSE)

И не забудьте свой ответ "засчитать" в системе, что бы другие на него опирались, на случай повторных проблем.

Comment: Смешно, я ещё до вашего комментария как раз так и сделал.  

    public static function getLastCrash($plc_id, $limit = 1, $desc = FALSE)
    {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;        
        $criteria->addInCondition('plc_id', (array) $plc_id);
    
        if ($desc == TRUE)
        {
            $criteria->order = 'id DESC';
        }
        else
        {
            $criteria->order = 'id';
        }
        $criteria->limit = $limit;
    
        return self::model()->findAll($criteria);
    }